# Creating a single-level list with lapply/sapply without coercion

Tags: r, lapply, sapply

Example data

```
> library(data.table)
> x <- c(as.IDate("2012-01-01"), as.IDate("2012-01-02"))
> x
[1] "2012-01-01" "2012-01-02"
> class(x)
[1] "IDate" "Date"
```

I would like to perform a function across the `vector`, and place the result in a single-level `list`. Here is the ideal outcome:

```
> y <- list(x = c(as.IDate("2012-01-01"), as.IDate("2012-01-02")))
> y
$x
[1] "2012-01-01" "2012-01-02"

> class(y)
[1] "list"
> class(y$x)
[1] "IDate" "Date"
```

I've tried these solutions, but `lapply` likes to build multi-level `list`s, and `sapply` likes to coerce my `IDate` to `integer`.

```
> list(x = lapply(x, function(x) x))
$x
$x[[1]]
[1] "2012-01-01"

$x[[2]]
[1] "2012-01-02"

> list(x = sapply(x, function(x) x))
$x
[1] 15340 15341
```

Note that `function(x)` is just a placeholder, I want to showcase that it's `sapply` is that doing the coercing, not the function.

How can I get around this?

Comment: Not clear why you need to do this `list(x=x)` seems to get the required output.

Comment: @arkun There is a function I need to run across the vector, that's why I'm using `sapply`/`lapply`. I didn't write out the actual function, because I wanted to showcase that the function itself wasn't doing the coercing.

Comment: Try with `lapply(list(x), function(x) ...)`

Comment: `sapply(y, function(x) x, simplify = FALSE)`

Comment: Thanks @arkun that did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use

```
lapply(list(x), yourfunction)
```